# In how many can $2$ apples, $3$ oranges, and $4$ mangoes be distributed to $3$ children if each child receives at least one fruit?

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways $2$ alike apple, $3$ alike orange and $4$ alike mango can be given to $3$ children if each child can have $1$ or more than $1$ fruits?

**solution** this is what I did. 
total number of ways without any restriction $= 900$. 
we have to subtract the case when at least one child doesn't get any fruit. 
let that be $C_1 \cup C_2 \cup C_3$
and we use the principle of mutual inclusion and exclusion to find that. 
$C_1 \cup C_2 \cup C_3 = C_1+C_2+C_3 - (\text{all two intersections}) + 3~\text{intersections}$ (no one gets a fruit case)
                          $= 3 \cdot 60 - 3+1 = 178$
so  case where each child gets at least one fruit $= 900-178 = 722$.

Is this right, someone saying answer $= 49$

Can this be solved by generating functions?

Comment: Is "no one gets a fruit" possible? You mean you can give out any number of fruits from $0$ to $9$? If that is so, how did you calculate $900$?

Comment: by using (n+r-1)C(r-1)  for  each of apple orange mango and multiplied them  , n =3 here  , r=2 for apple , 3 for mango and  4 for mango

Comment: Yes, that's how I would calculate it, **assuming that all of the pieces of fruit are to be given out**. But your solution implies that not all of the pieces are to be given out, since you have a "no one gets a fruit" case.

Comment: assume  1 child get no fruit then for apple child left 2 , r = 2 and            
     apple =2 = n   then  ( n+r-1) c (r-1)  =  3   same for remaining you will get 60

Comment: There should be no $+1$ term since it is not possible to distribute the fruit to none of the children.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The answer cannot be $49$.  As you determined, there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to distribute the apples and $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to distribute the oranges, so there are $\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2} = 60$ ways to distribute the apples and oranges.  No matter how they are distributed, we can ensure that each child receives a fruit by giving any child who has not yet received a fruit a mango before distributing the mangoes that remain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As N. F. Taussig notes you are off by $1$.
Denote by $C_i$ the set of distributions where child${}_{\,i}\>$ receives no fruit. Then
$$|C_1\cup C_2\cup C_3|=\sum_i |C_i|-\sum_{i<j} |C_i\cap C_j|+|C_1\cap C_2\cap C_3|\ .\tag{1}$$
You correctly computed $|C_i|=60$ and $|C_i\cap C_j|=1$ when $i\ne j$, but $|C_1\cap C_2\cap C_3|=0$. The threefold intersection consists of all distributions where none of the children receives a fruit. But since in fact $9$ pieces are handed out at least one of the kids has to obtain one.

From $(1)$ we obtain
$$|C_1\cup C_2\cup C_3|=3\cdot 60-3\cdot 1=177\ ,$$
so that the number of admissible distributions comes to $900-177=723$.

A generating function approach would not pay out: The allowed allocations for one child are encoded in the function
$$p(x,y,z):={1\over (1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}-1={x+y+z-xy-xz-yz+xyz\over(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}\ .$$
You would then have to determine the coefficient of $x^2y^3z^4$ in the power series for $\bigl(p(x,y,z)\bigr)^3$.

Comment: thnku sir for helping me :)

Comment: sir  i have a doubt  if number of persons becomes 10 then how to solve in that case mutual exclusion formula will become very large  plz help

Comment: There are not enough fruit for $10$ people. Apart from that you would have to go through the full inclusion/exclusion process.

Comment: sorry sir  i was interpreting it wrong , can you tell me if in question atleast 2 given  then  we have to subtract  723 -( exactly 1)  am i right

Comment: Ask a new question.

Comment: In how many can 2  apples, 3 oranges, and 4 mangoes be distributed to 3 children if each child receives at least 2 fruit?