# generating functions permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many different ways $10$ identical ball can be distributed among $3$ children, if each receives atleast $2$ balls and no more than $4$ balls ?

**Solution**
Distribute $10$ identical ball $\rightarrow 3$ distinct children

$$x_1+x_2+x_3 = 10$$  where $2\le  x_i \le 4$

now I am not able to find how to approach by generating functions , since I am new to it  please explain in detail

Comment: **Hint:** How many possible arrangements of $(2,3,4)$ and $(3,3,4)$ are possible?

Comment: you post your solution

Comment: @Sumit Goyal You are welcome. And welcome to MSE. If your doubts about the question get cleared on this site then mark the appropriate answer as "accepted" by ticking grey tick to make it green consequently .

Comment: yes sir i did it , sir please check link  --->  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2617284/in-how-many-can-2-apples-3-oranges-and-4-mangoes-be-distributed-to-3-c/2617656#2617656             here a person provided answer to my  question and here in second link question appears to be same  but they are taking 10C1 , 10C2  ..... extra   here is link please resolve https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597951/in-how-many-ways-can-6-red-and-6-blue-balls-be-distributed-among-10-person?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use generating functions,  the star and bars method suffices to solve the problem.

According to the question each child must get at least $2$ balls.
Hence the answer to the question would be the number of non negative integral solutions to the equation 
$$ a+b+c=4$$
And coincidentally in none of the cases does a child get more than 4 balls, using the star and bars intuition. 
Hence the answer would be $$\binom {6}{2}=15$$

Method 2 :-

Each child must get either $2,3$ or $4$ balls and there are total four balls to be distributed among 3 children 
Hence the generating function would be -

We need to find the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the expansion 
$$(x^2+x^3+x^4)(x^2+x^3+x^4)(x^2+x^3+x^4)=(x^2+x^3+x^4)^3= x^6 .(1-x^3)^3. (1-x)^{-3}$$

I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: i want to learn generating function thats why yes no need to use but your approach becomes tedious for large values

Comment: @Sumit Goyal Learning generating functions is a bit broad category because it differs from question to question, and over  what you have been asked. If you want to learn the method of generating functions you must try a good book on combinatorics and relating them to formation of functions. However I have provided a hint for the generating function method.